# html5 a download attribute doesn't work when the url is a blob url

Tags: javascript, download, html5-video

We're creating a chrome extension to download videos, currently I have this function :

```
function downloadvideo(video)
{
    const url = URL.createObjectURL(video.captureStream());
    const aelem = document.createElement('a');
    document.body.appendChild(aelem);
    aelem.setAttribute("href",url);
    aelem.setAttribute("download","video.mp4");
    aelem.click();
    //URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
}
```

Here `video` parameter is a html5 video element, I'm using `caputreStream` because some websites(notably youtube) uses blob url which are revoked apparently So I create a new Blob url from `MediaStream`.

The function above is executed as part of video's `onloadeddata` event.

The dialog is shown and the filename is correct but when I click "Save" chrome says "failed : could not find the file".

So how to make it actually work ?

By the way I tried to do ajax against `url` but chrome refuses with the message : "Cross-origin is only supported for schemes http,https,chrome,chrome-extension" :3 .

Comment: can you play the temp video url in a new video tag?

Comment: @dandavis No I can't, no error in console, the new video tag is black blank and clicking the play button doesn't do anything(except that the timer increases but the slider doesn't slide)

Comment: sounds like it's possibly still loading when you grab it, or that it is blocked and won't work at all...

Comment: @dandavis ok sorry but yes it does play but only when the original video plays and it just follows it

Comment: @dandavis and the audio sounds hmm duplicating :)

Comment: I already faced this, I think you should  ajax/xhr the elements, from the current page. You can then declare the origin as trusted in the ajax function. But to really avoid cors blocking, you must proxy your streams by your server, with CORS enabled. This is how it works.

Comment: @Cryptopat sorry I didn't understand you, what do you mean by "ajax/xhr the elements" ?

Comment: Well, to simplify, it is a regular blocking. Whatever you are trying to load as a local blob, or in the web audio api, need to be CORS enabled. You can test your url's here: http://www.test-cors.org/
If the server dissalow CORS, you need to serve the content by your server. The process would be to CURL the content and serve it with the header Access-Control-Allow-Origin: * ,via ajax. You would then be abble to load your file as a blob, and manipulate it.

Answer (score 2):

URL.createObjectURL()

Note: The use of a MediaStream object as an input to this method is in the process of being deprecated. Discussions are ongoing about whether or not it should be removed outright. As such, you should try to avoid using this method with MediaStreams, and should use HTMLMediaElement.srcObject() instead.

Ref : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/createObjectURL#Browser_compatibility

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/srcObject#Browser_compatibility

Code :

function downloadvideo(video)
{

```
var mediaStream = video.captureStream();
//adding a dom element and fetching it in HTMLMediaElement.

HTMLMediaElement.srcObject = mediaStream;
var url = HTMLMediaElement.currentSrc;
const aelem = document.createElement('a');
document.body.appendChild(aelem);
aelem.setAttribute("href",url);
aelem.setAttribute("download","video.mp4");
aelem.click();
//URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
```

}

See if this works for you.

Comment: sorry but didn't work, the same thing, thanks anyway :)

Comment: I'll see if there is a workaround possible for this.

Answer (score 0):

Here is is function which i used to download video in bloburl which i stored from canvas frame capture

```
function createdVideo(){
        var output = 'your video or captured stream or canvas capture'  
        var url = webkitURL.createObjectURL(output);
        // output_video.src = url; //toString converts it to a URL via Object URLs, falling back to DataURL
        download.href = url;//download is id of download link which als ohave download atribute}
```

i Hope will work in your case

Comment: My function is the same as your solution